# Как подогнать ширину блока под ширину контента

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Обычно я делаю так:

```
<div style="background: #f00;float:left">Тут немного текста</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Может есть более человеческие варианты?

Comment: Человечески - это как? так как вы себе придумали?

Comment: А что Вы понимаете под шириной контента?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот [так можно сделать](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/SePFr/1/):

```
div {
    display: inline-block; /* или display: inline; в зависимости от задач */
    background: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
div {
    width: fit-content;
}
```